# Sql server should be in the same system when hosting Web service in IIS

Tags: asp.net, sql, wcf, entity-framework, iis

I created a WCF service in that i am using entity framework where Sql server is located in another system. I created a web-application and consuming the service and i am having no trouble with the entity framework. When i host my web service in IIS i am getting exception in my entity framework saying **underlying provider failed on open**. I goggled but nothing works.

Comment: you should solve credential issue and get permission

Answer (score 0):

As folks mentioned IIS user network service user credentials while trying to log in sql server. So just change the Application pool settings in your IIS.

```
Step 1:
Open Internet Information Service Manager
Step 2:
Click on Application Pools in left navigation tree.
Step 3:
Select your version Pool. In my case, I am using ASP .Net v4.0. If you dont have this version, select DefaultAppPool.
Step 4:
Right click on step 3, and select advanced settings.
Step 5:
Select Identity in properties window and click the button to change the value.
Step 6:
Select Local System in Built-in accounts combo box and click ok.
That's it. Now run your application. Everything works well.
```

**Also check this :**

http://stack247.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/entity-framework-exception-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open/

**and**

http://stack247.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/wcf-exception-in-iis-only-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open-access-to-entity-framework/

Comment: My IIS version is 5.1 i am unable to find Application pool where i can find ?

Comment: create a new virtual directory under the Default Web site and make it an application.

Comment: I already created virtual directory to my service do i need to create my web application too

Comment: if you have created vd , you will need to create application. actually all the vesions below IIS 6 does not have this feature. After IIS6 [including it] you can create separate application pool.